# Reading a nested json file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
  "men_rankings": {
    "abe": ["cat", "bea", "ada"],
    "bob": ["ada", "cat", "bea"],
    "cal": ["ada", "bea", "cat"]
  },

  "women_rankings": {
    "ada": ["abe", "cal", "bob"],
    "bea": ["bob", "abe", "cal"],
    "cat": ["cal", "abe", "bob"]
  }
}
```

and I want to save in two lists the men's and women's names (I am working in python). (I just want this: `mens = ['abe', 'cal', 'bob']`). An other user may give totally different names so I have to find a way to save the names without knowing for example that men's names are abe, cal, bob. If I use this way:

```
import json
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
j = json.load(f)
f.close()
```

in variable `j` there will be all the contents of the file without knowing what the names are. Have you any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `women = j[ "women_rankings"].keys()` and `men = j[ "men_rankings"].keys()` gives what you exxpect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extract all the keys from the dicts within your `j` variable with the [`.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) method, as such:

```
men = j['men_rankings'].keys()
women = j['women_rankings'].keys()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the names. `json.loads()` converts this to a Python data structure, in this case nested dicts. Dicts have a `keys()` method that gives the keys. So:

```
mens = j['men_rankings'].keys()
womens = j['women_rankings'].keys()
```